# EditText is not showing hint on changing the height of EditText

Tags: android, android-layout

EditText is not showing hint on changing the height of the EditText
This is my code

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16dp"/>
```

[image]

Comment: make height as wrap_content or more than 40dp

Comment: @Azharosws But I want to change the height of edittext what should I do for that?

Comment: @AhsanAzwar check my answer if you want to go with the fixed height. Although this is not recommended to use hardcoded heights. instead use wrap_content like suggested by other answers/comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its because of your `layout_height`

your `layout_height` should be at least `36dp` to show your text.
Also your should use `sp` for text size not `dp`

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"  // 36 dp or more or wrap_content
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are giving too less `height` as compared to your `textSize`. if you really want to go with this size then you need to give `padding in "-"`(minus)

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
    android:padding="-5dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sky Alligator mentioned correctly but still then you want to maintain height=20dp, go for this one. 
Either set

```
android:background="@null"
```

Or

```
android:background="@drawable/bg_rect_edittext"
```

bg_rect_edittext.xml

```
<item xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Hopefully this may help you!